# Email sent when inserting ContentDocumentLink record

Tags: apex, email, chatter, files, contentdocumentlink

I have noticed that when using Apex to programmatically insert a list of ContentDocumentLink records that the users specified in the LinkedEntityId are receiving an email notifying them that the document has been shared with them.

The reply email seems to be a Chatter related email address, and I have determined that you can suppress the email that is sent to the user by unchecking *Allow Emails* in the user's **Chatter Email Settings**. Unfortunately, this needs to be done per user.

Is there another way to accomplish this without touching the Chatter email settings?